# MonoDevelop can't import VS2013/2015 solutions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mono-framework, monodevelop

I'm opening a `.sln` file that I transferred from Visual Studio 2013 into MonoDevelop. When I attempt this, however, it gives me the following error(s):

```
1. Project 'foo' has a different ToolsVersion than the containing solution.
2. Error while trying to load the project '/path/to/foo.csproj': Unknown ToolsVersion '12.0'
3. [repeat 2 for every project in the solution]
```

When I tried doing this for a VS2015 file, it game me the same errors, except this time `ToolsVersion` was `14.0`.

My MonoDevelop version is v4.0.12; is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Manually modify the solution file do its compatible with the program